# ES Date Histogram Bucket max item count

Tags: javascript, c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have timeSeries based data.

Im performing a date histogram aggregation with interval '1h' and sorting the results by "_count". Is it possible to limit the item count in the bucket so it would only return the 1st one, the item with the maximum count and not bother about the other ?

Thanks